# Multiple tables in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter

I really need some kind of help/reference that deals with already created databases with multiple tables, gathering information from the tables and using that information in the app.  All I can find are examples/tutorials that you create your database from scratch or it only deals with 1 database table.  Does anyone know of any tutorials/references out there that explicitly deal with what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + tbPerson +
                    " (" +
                    PERSON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    PERSON_NAME + " TEXT)";
private static final String COLOR_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + tbColor +
                    " (" +
                    COLOR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLOR_NAME + " TEXT)";
```

And in onCreate method of your database helper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(PERSON_TABLE_CREATE);
            mDatabase.execSQL(COLOR_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

Tutorial :

[link](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html)